# MSVC++ more than one console window

Tags: visual-c++, console, window

In MSVC++ you can summon a console window to your app by running:

```
// Attach a console
AllocConsole() ;
AttachConsole( GetCurrentProcessId() ) ;
freopen( "CON", "w", stdout ) ;
```

Now `printf` and `cout` automatically go to that window.

Is it possible in MSVC++ to have **more than one** console window?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think so but there are a few logging libraries that give you a console-like dos box that you can stream messages to.   You could have lots of these if you just one a number of separate output consoles.

Answer (score 0):

According to [AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944) documentation:

> A process can be associated with only
>   one console

So I don't think you can use multiple consoles. MSVC++ is not responsible for this, it's a Win32 limitation.